# условие if при axios ответе

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel5, laravel-5.7

подскажите, почему не срабатывает условие if всегда выдает alert

```
.then((response) => {
   console.log(response.data);
   if (response.data === "true") this.like++; else alert(response.data);
})
```

хотя котроллер отдает

```
return 'true';
```

Comment: А что в консоли?

Comment: в консоле true и alert true

Comment: Я могу предположить, что приходит не строка, а буль. А сравнение в ифе идёт еще и по типу. Попробуй сравнить не так `===`, а так `==`. Если будет продолжать уходить в `else`, тогда мало кода для анализа косяка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Запишите по-человечески `if/else`, а не как сейчас - ни два, ни полтора.
- Используя строгое сравнение `===`, проверяйте тип данных `console.log(typeof response.data)`
- Из контроллера возвращайте ответ:

```
return response()
  ->json([
    'message' => 'Ваш голос принят.',
    // Возвращайте количество лайков,
    // после изменений в БД.
    'likes' => 520,
  ], 200);
```

Соответственно в компоненте:

```
.then((response) => {
  this.like = response.data.likes;

  alert(response.data.message);
})
.catch((error) => {
  if (error.response) {
    // Запрос сделан, и сервер ответил кодом состояния, который выпадает из диапазона 2xx.
  } else if (error.request) {
    // Ошибка запроса.
  } else {
    // Остальные ошибки.
  }
});
```

---

**UPD**

Коды ответов, используемые в Laravel: [github](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/63c5302d9af9038ea41cd140f1e54c32b9f98ed7/Response.php#L19). `axios` по умолчанию отлавливает статус ответов (коды) `status >= 200 && status < 300` в `then` методе, все остальные уходят в `catch`.

Comment: не понял Запишите по-человечески if/else

Comment: Хотите в одну строку - используйте тернарный оператор `response.data ? действие_1 : действие_2` Если уж написали `if/else` то разбейте на строки.

Comment: а понятно, а еще вопрос, 200 это я так понимаю статус, а если ничего не вернет?

Comment: Когда вы пишите из контроллера `return 'true'` Laravel сам решает в каком виде вернуть ответ, например `json` и сам ставит код ответа, например `200`. Желательно ведь контролировать данный процесс, не так ли?

Comment: а где глянуть список кодов для ответа?

Comment: да помог, просто как вызвать например catch?

Comment: да, про него, то есть посылать 500 в return?

Comment: да, там помогли, я отметил прошу прощения, забыл

Comment: а catch какой код вызывает?